# JpaRepository makes two identical queries to database while retreiving simple entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a very primitive Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
}
```

I use a simple JpaRepository<Person, Integer> with no overriding methos. Whenever I invoke repository.findAll()method I get the following log:

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
select
        person0_.id as id1_2_,
        person0_.address as address2_2_,
        person0_.name as name3_2_ 
    from
        person person0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        person0_.id as id1_2_,
        person0_.address as address2_2_,
        person0_.name as name3_2_ 
    from
        person person0_
```

The same result I get invoking repository.getOne(). Repository while trying to get a very simple data uses two identical queries one after another with seemingly no particular reason. Is this just how it visualise or is it actually making two queries instead of one? Why is that?

Comment: I doubt it is actually making two calls to the d/b. You could perhaps check the db access logs ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the same query being logged twice?

Comment: `findAll()` makes a single query unless there is a lazy loaded dependent entity(N+1 in this case, and not identical). The log seems the same line logged twice.

Comment: show here application.properties file here?

Comment: @priyranjan I have show_sql=true, format_sql_true and use_sql_comments=true. Tryed to remove "show_sql" and now it's logging once.

Comment: did not get what are you trying to say? spring.jpa.show-sql=true this will print query in console.

Comment: @priyranjan i disabled show_sql and queries are still printing and not duplicating

Comment: that's why I ask you to show your application.properties file n relavent code here. How ppl will help you with just piece of code. did you get my point now?